# Want to exclude slider from page.php in header

Tags: page-template, exclude

I know this is a dumb question, but for the love of my life, I can't get the code to work. I have three page templates: home, page and another page-by category. I have a slider that I want to excluded from the default page.php file but to show everywhere else. I have tried to do this with `is_page_template` , but that isn't working. any help will be much appreciated. I'm not sure if you need my header  code. If you do then leave a comment please and I'll paste in in pastebin. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: For future reference: **yes**, *always* include relevant code in your question. Please post the code **in the question**, *not* in a Pastebin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you consult [the `is_page_template()` Codex entry](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template)?

If you want to query for the `page.php` page template, then you need to pass that filename to `is_page_template()`; i.e.:

```
<?php
if ( ! is_page_template( 'page.php' ) ) {
    // The current page template is NOT page.php;
    // do something
}
?>
```

Sidenote: if you want to query for being a static page AND not a specific page template:

```
<?php
if ( is_page() && ! is_page_template( 'page.php' ) ) {
    // Current page is a static page AND
    // The current page template is NOT page.php;
    // do something
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks chip. the second solution works!!! I did not know to do that!